# Append only unique elements to the array of objects in Angular2

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, angular, typescript

I have got two arrays of objects - new and old one. Object must be compared by one unique field (MAC address). I want to get third array or append it to the existing old one and add only new objects.

For example

```
oldArray = [{mac: 11}, {mac: 12}, {mac: 14}];
newArray = [{mac: 11}, {mac: 13}, {mac: 14}];
```

I want to return array like this:

`array = [{mac: 11}, {mac: 12}, {mac:13}, {mac: 14}]`

I have managed to do similar thing in Swift using contains method but could not come up with solution in typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like

```
let oldArray = [{mac: 11}, {mac: 12}, {mac: 14}];
let newArray = [{mac: 11}, {mac: 13}, {mac: 14}];
let tempSet = new Set([...oldArray, ...newArray].map(i => JSON.stringify(i)));
let resultArray = Array.from(tempSet).map(i => JSON.parse(i));

console.log(resultArray); // [{mac: 11}, {mac: 12}, {mac:13}, {mac: 14}]
```

JSON parse/stringify makes this work for any type of object as an arrays item, not only for single-property object like `{mac: N}`.

---

And two versions based on `Array.prototype.reduce`, without intermediate `Set`.

Explicit (mac prop object):

```
let resultArray = [...oldArray, ...newArray].reduce((s, i) => 
  !s.some(j => i.mac === j.mac) ? [...s, i] : s
, []);
```

Generic (any object):

```
let resultArray = [...oldArray, ...newArray].reduce((s, i) => 
  !s.some(j => JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(j)) ? [...s, i] : s
, []);
```

Comment: @codddeer123 I just added two new versions to the answer. Maybe they will be more appropriate for you.

Comment: How can I check another condition? For example I would like not to add it when MAC address is the same but update the object when new value (of other field) is higher than the old one.

Comment: @codddeer123 `!s.some(j => i.mac === j.mac)` -- here the place for filtering condition, for example `!s.some(j => (i.mac === j.mac || i.newValue > j.newValue))` will add second object with same macs but different newValue

Comment: I tried something like this yesterday but it didn't work. I will take a look again when I'm back home.

Comment: @codddeer123 You may post a new question. If nobody replies, put here a link and I will have a look.